# React JS - Change color on click and put defaul color on all other ones

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have "x" number of rendered ***ArticlePreview*** components that depends of API call.

```html
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="flex-grid">
    { Object.keys(images).map((index, i) => { return (
    <ArticlePreview onClick={(evt)=>this.props.clicked(evt, i)} img={images[index]} title={titles[index]} description={descriptions[index]} key={i}> </ArticlePreview>) }) }
  </div>
</div>
```

I can change color of div from specific component when I click on it.

```html
articleClicked =(evt, i) => { evt.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; }
```

But whet I click to another component, color of previois clicked stays as clicked and I want it to change it to default value if I click another component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dev's Answer it is a better way to use React props and state.

It is necessary to pass the click Handler function to `div` because `onClick` props works on `DOM elements` but `React.Component`.

This is [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/113099/) and it is similar with @Dev's

You can refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html for more info.

Comment: Used your solution for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> By leveraging `state management`, you can achieve that. Please find below sample for reference.
>   Avoid `DOM Manipulations` and let react take care of that.

```js
const ArticlePreview = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className={props.class} onClick={props.onClick}>{props.article}</div>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      selected: false,
      article: ''
    }
  }
  
  onSelectArticle = (article) => {
   this.setState({
     selected:true,
     article:article
   })
  }
  
  render() {
    let articles = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    
    return <div>
    {
      articles.map((article, index)=> <ArticlePreview key={index} class={(this.state.selected && (this.state.article === article)) ? 'bkcolor': 'default'} onClick={() => this.onSelectArticle(article)} article={article}/>)
    }
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById("app"))
```

```css
.default {
  background: transparent
}
.bkcolor {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In your case, pass the index to the handler and check the selected and match the index state.

```
 ...
<ArticlePreview className={(this.state.selected && (this.state.index === index)) ? 'bkcolor': 'default'} onClick={()=>this.props.clicked(index)} img={images[index]} title={titles[index]} description={descriptions[index]} key={i}> </ArticlePreview>) }) }
 ...
```