# Make the clicked LI a different color, but then have that LI go back to normal when you click a different LI

Tags: reactjs

I have a set of LIs, each with a clickhandler that adds a className (via event.currentTarget) that has a CSS rule to be red. So, when you click one, it turns red, as desired. When you click a different one, the one you just clicked turns red and the one you clicked first is still red. How do I return the previously clicked LI to default color when I click a different one?

```
selectItem(event) {
let item = event.currentTarget.innerText
event.currentTarget.className += ' red'
this.setState({selectedItemText: item}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.selectedItemText);
})
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944971/react-js-change-color-on-click-and-put-defaul-color-on-all-other-ones/48945338#48945338

Answer (score 0):

Try this example and make use of state management to save the state of clicked element

```
 this.state = {clicked_index: 0};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/113099/

Comment: is there a way in react to find all elements with a certain class and remove that class? seems like that could also work if i put it at the top of my function